# How to correct javascript button's redirect?

Tags: javascript

I'am trying to add some js to my page, I create from it's a button and the aim of creating it is to redirect to another page but it is not working. Can you help me to solve it?

The situation is: the button is visible on my front-end (.jsp in Java EE), but there is no redirect. No matter what I write in URL simply no action is being made form click.

```
    buttonAbort.innerHTML = 'Anuluj';
    buttonAbort.style.cssFloat = 'left';
    buttonAbort.style.width = '70px';
    buttonAbort.style.height = '30px';
    buttonAbort.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    button.setAttribute("id","buttonAbort");

    let buttonAbortById = document.getElementById("buttonAbort");
    buttonAbortById.onclick = function href() {
        location.href="/projekt/edytujStatus";
    }
```

Comment: Where are you appending the button to the page?

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have a mistake in your code.

You probably want to do

```js
buttonAbort.setAttribute("id","buttonAbort");
```

instead of

```js
button.setAttribute("id","buttonAbort");
```

Comment: I would add that I see no reason to assign the id to button (`buttonAbort.setAttribute("id","buttonAbort")`) and then to find the button by id (`let buttonAbortById = document.getElementById("buttonAbort")`) at all. IMHO, `buttonAbort.onclick = …` would be enough.